# Using angular foreach loop to rearrange JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, foreach

I have an ng-repeat which returns arrays of objects like the following:

```
[{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]
[{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]
```

I'd like to have pull out the objects and push them into another array so they are formatted like this:

```
[
{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"},
    {"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"
}]
```

The goal is to use an orderBy on the array. Is it possible to restructure the JSON into this format and then access the data?

Here is my view for reference:

```
<div class="calDynamic" data-ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
<div ng-repeat="cal in calendar[n].year | filterKey:month">

    <p>{{cal}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

My JSON format:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53f252537d343a9ad862866c"),
"year" : {
    "December" : [],
    "November" : [],
    "October" : [],
    "September" : [],
    "August" : [],
    "July" : [ 
        {
            "day" : "21",
            "title" : "u",
            "summary" : "u",
            "description" : "ok",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53f252537d343a9ad862866d")
        }
    ],
    "June" : [],
    "May" : [],
    "April" : [],
    "March" : [],
    "February" : [],
    "January" : []
},
"__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f252537d343a9ad862866c"),
    "year" : {
        "December" : [],
        "November" : [],
        "October" : [],
        "September" : [],
        "August" : [],
        "July" : [ 
            {
                "day" : "3",
                "title" : "u",
                "summary" : "u",
                "description" : "ok",
                "_id" : ObjectId("53f252537d343a9ad862866d")
            }
        ],
        "June" : [],
        "May" : [],
        "April" : [],
        "March" : [],
        "February" : [],
        "January" : []
    },
    "__v" : 0
    }
```

Comment: Array.concat is what you are looking for?

Comment: that may be I haven't looked into that

Comment: So you want to merge all of arrays in months to one array?

Comment: Yes, here is an example JSfiddle with the logic I'd like to use. I just need to reorder my data into one array. http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/dc9wtn0y/

Comment: Try `var result  = [].concat.apply([], Object.keys(obj.year).map(function(key){ return obj.year[key]; }));` I cannot access fiddle. You have a js bin?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/zijonivisoto/1/ like this?

Comment: I have it formatted a little differently. I've edited the JSON above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just elaborating my comment to answer:-

You can do this way to merge the arrays scattered across various month to 1 array.

```
//obj has the the array result that is the input
var temp = [];
var result = temp.concat.apply(temp,obj.map(function(itm){ //Get each object in the source array that hold the year.
  return temp.concat.apply(temp, Object.keys(itm.year).map(function(key){ //Get Month for each yeah and flatten it out
       return itm.year[key]; //Get day array for each of the month in each year
  }));
}));
```

[`Object.keys(obj.year)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ==> Will give you the months in your property `Year` to an array
[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ==> You pass in the months array and get back 2D array of days from all of months.
[`[].concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) ==> returns array of concatenated arrays. It can take multiple arrays are argument, so we use [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) conveniently to convert 2D to 1D.

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/zijonivisoto/1/edit)**

Other simple and performance effective way always is loop through and add upon.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps me out tremendously. Would there be any way to pass the filtered objects from the view back into the controller. I currently have the objects being filtered by the key matching the routeparam. It would be perfect if I could do the array flattening after the filtering has happened, instead of for the entire data set.

Comment: @byrdr Yes you could do that and that would be better as well since there is only less count to be iterated. You could move this to a filter and add this filter next to your other filter

Comment: Thanks, @PSL does this look right? angular.module('hcApp')
.filter('super', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var temp = [];
    var result = temp.concat.apply(temp,input.map(function(itm){ 
      return temp.concat.apply(temp, Object.keys(itm.year).map(function(key){ 
       return itm.year[key]; 
  }));
}));  
    return result;
  };
});

Comment: Yeah looks fin.. But you would need to try it out combining with the other filter.

Comment: Looks like the filter is set up correctly. The two filters paired don't seem to work together for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Array.prototype.concat** allows to join two arrays into one. However, it is just javascript and has nothing to do with Angular, the way to do it is like:

```
var a =  [{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}];
var b = [{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}];

var c = a.concat(b); // returns the concatenated array.
```

Comment: This may be difficult to use in the view since objects are coming from a CMS without assigned variable names.

Comment: if objects are not assigned to variables how on earth did angular access it?

Comment: I've added my JSON to the question.